# Impedance matching on DC voltage line to remove ringing/reflections

Tags: dc, impedance, reflection

I'm generating a 6 MHz signal in an Altera FPGA. I am feeding this 1.8 V signal out through a level shifter to 3.3 V to a connector on the board. This is the signal at that connector:

[image: First signal]

I am then sending this 3.3 V signal back into the FPGA (stepped down to 1.8 V). It comes out of the FPGA (stepped back up to 3.3 V) and is brought out on another connector on the board. This is the signal at that connector:

[image: Second signal]

There is a lot of ringing from reflections on the line which I am trying to dampen. I have put a 33 ohm resistor in series on the track, but it didn't help.

What do I do to match the impedance? I only have hobbyist level electronics.

Comment: 1) include a schematic with as many details as possible 2) it is possible that there's ringing **because you're measuring at that point with a probe** 3) are you using a 10:1 probe ? 4) The ringing might not even be an issue. 5) for a 6 MHz clock on a PCB, you don't really need impedance matching.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks, I will draw up a schematic of the setup. Ringing is definitely an issue as I am routing a jtag singal through the fpga and the first peak is being interpreted as high.

Comment: Frequency does not really matter for ringing. Rise time does. What is your rise time?

Answer (score 2):

At 20 ns/division, edge rates of 2 ns, you need to dampen; use 50 ohms and 33/47/68/100 pF in series from trace/wire to GND. Or try 100 ohms and a small capacitor.

By the way, your ringing frequency of 100 MHz is where 15 pF probes and 100 nH scope-probe ground leads (6") resonate.

Bypass your ICs, right at the package. Using SMT capacitors. On ground planes.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use the best possible measuring methods with the scope to avoid the introduction of false impressions. Short GND lead referenced right at the load measure point.

Make sure the series resistor in the signal line is as close to the driver output as possible.

The series resistor value may have to be adjusted up or down to improve the line match.

For particularly critical applications you may need to place a pullup and pulldown on the very end of the line to match line impedance and prevent reflections. The match impedance is the parallel equivalent resistance of the two resistors.

If you have this all built on a proto plug board with flying wires everywhere the pictures of the waveforms may be as good as it gets.

Comment: thank you. It is a printed PCB. Is there method to calculate the values of the pullup and pulldown?

Comment: There are ways to calculate if you know the details of the circuit board trace impedance and if the traces were laid out with a sense of controlling the impedance. Often it can be way easier to start with the two resistors equal in value and then manually try values to see if there is improvement. Line end terminations can be tricky though because you also have to make sure that the driver at the head end of the line can source and sink the additional current while still maintaining valid high / low logic levels. This is why series termination at the driver is used most often.

Answer (score 2):

From the output pin of your FPGA you may adjust the slew rate or at least get the information of the slew rate.

If there is parasitic inductance on your wire, this ringing will be generated due to the voltage at an inductance given by
U = di/dt at each switching.

The ringing could occur due to extra inductance, brought into the system by your probe. If possible, try to use a ground like in the picture. 
Maybe your signal is much more beautiful in reality without the probe.

[Link](https://www.calplus.de/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2Ftektronix-tpp0250-tpp0500b-handbuch-englisch-071316400.pdf)

[image: Probe with short GND connection]

Comment: Please tell us, if this was sufficient.